# How to listen or watch pod ip change event history in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, java-client

I want to save the history pod ip changes for troubleshooting in future.
How can i do that ?
Is there api in k8s io.fabric client i can use?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: This doesn't seem like the sort of debugging question that needs code to understand, so I'm not sure why code would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch on endpoints and not pods itself.

Eg.

```
 try (Watch watch = client.endpoints().inNamespace(namespace).watch(new Watcher<Endpoints>() {
        @Override
        public void eventReceived(Action action, Endpoints resource) {
        ....//your code
         }
     ....
```